# Laravel - queue driver database not working

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

In my laravel app I have set up table for jobs in my database, and setup the .env file with database driver, I run `php artisan queue:work` in terminal, but nothing gets uploaded when I try to upload it like that, but when I use sync driver everything works fine.
Not sure why is that and how to fix it so that it works with database driver?

Answer (score 0):

I your terminal run the following

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Sometimes when a value is changed in your .env file, you might have to run the aove listed commands for them to take effect. It worked for me

Answer (score -2):

To process new jobs you need to run:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

in console as mentioned in [Queues documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

Comment: Just to add my two cents, if you run laravel `5.2` or lower, you have to run `php artisan queue:work --daemon`

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.3 and I do run php artisan queue:work I forgot to mention that in my post, but still it didn't work.